# search a string in a files if it match replace another string in the same line with some string

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, tcl

```
h -t 9.641909323 -s 0 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1078 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
r -t 9.650534114 -s 29 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1020 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
+ -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC 
- -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
h -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
```

here i need to search **-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr**   if its match with any line on that line replace initial **h** with **d**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the line matches the pattern and the first field is `h` set the first field to `d`:

```
$ awk '/-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr/&&$1=="h"{$1="d"}1' file
d -t 9.641909323 -s 0 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1078 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
r -t 9.650534114 -s 29 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1020 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
+ -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
- -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
h -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
```

**Edit:**

Only replace the first match:

```
$ awk '/-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr/&&$1=="h"&&!f{$1="d";f=1}1' file
d -t 9.641909323 -s 0 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1078 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
r -t 9.650534114 -s 29 -d 29 -p cbr -e 1020 -c 2 -a 0 -i 169 -k MAC
+ -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
- -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
h -t 9.650544114 -s 29 -d -1 -p ACK -e 38 -c 2 -a 0 -i 0 -k MAC
```

Comment: but its not replace all the lines its replace only first line my file contains nearly 10000 lines

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned this in the question!? See the new script to only change the first occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

With Tcl, you'd write a somewhat longer program than in those other languages:

```
# Open the files for streaming...
set filename "whatever.log"
set fin [open $filename]
set fout [file tempfile tempName]

# Process the lines, one by one...
while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {   ### <<< THIS IS IDIOMATIC FOR STREAMING
    if {[string first "-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr" $line]} {
        regsub "^h" $line "d" line
    }
    puts $fout $line
}

# Finalize everything
close $fin
close $fout
file rename $tempName $filename
```

If you want the output to go to a different file, you can just use:

```
set fout [open "differentFile.txt" "w"]
```

instead of the `set fout [file tempfile tempName]` and omit the `file rename`. (That will also make the code work on all versions of Tcl earlier than 8.6; `file tempfile` is a new feature, but everything else used here has been around for ages.)

---

Alternatively, for a version that reads in all the lines at once, replace the central processing loop with this one-liner that uses line-mode RE substitution and a little bit of smartness:

```
# Use [puts -nonewline] because the last newline is kept with [read]
puts -nonewline $fout [regsub -all -line "^h(.*-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr)" [read $fin] "d\\1"]
```

This will, however, hold all the data in memory at once.

Comment: BTW, for 10k of lines with those sorts of line lengths, I'd do it all in memory. It's less than a MB of data, and we've all got computers with multiple GB of physical RAM…

Answer (score 2):

try below sed one-liner:

```
sed '/-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr/s/^h/d/' file
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but : How come your code line has colors and not mine? (same line...)

Comment: @xShirase Because you mentioned in answer, you are not sure if it will work. :D  just kidding. I don't know how does SO do the code highlighting. but the difference is, I have another part after the quoted segment, which is the input file. yours doesn't. That might be a condition for SO to highlight syntax?

Comment: it seems that the code gets highlighted when you use the 4space indentation, but not when you use the backquotes. Further research shows it won't highlight backquoted code even if indented. Thanks ^^

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it at all. good to know. I write/edit my post in vim, vim does indentation for me. I just pressed `Tab`

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, I can't test here, something like :

```
sed '/-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr/s/^h/d/'
```

should work. Let me know or edit. I'll be able to check only later. Good luck!

Comment: But, This expression will replace the `h` with `^d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,

```
sed  '/-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr/{s/^h\(.*\)/d\1/g}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

By *initial* `h`, you seem to refer to the first character in the matching line.  By that assumption, the following should work:

```
grep -- "-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr" inputfile | sed 's/^h/d/'
```

Comment: thanks its replace correctly and displayed  but my inputfile didn't change.

Comment: This wasn't supposed to change the input file.  Was it?  Try something like:  `cp inputfile tmpfile && grep -- "-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr" tmpfile | sed 's/^h/d/' > inputfile`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^h(.*-s 0 -d 29 -p cbr)/d\1/' file
```